# If i want to run java programs downloading on the fly. what do i need to do?

Tags: java

If i want to run java programs downloading on the fly. what do i need to do?

Comment: sorry couldn't get you point? will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [java web start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html).